# PHP If String Contains A Comma Query

Tags: php

I have a string stored in a field in my db of comma separated values and some which are not comma separated.

e.g.

```
Red
Blue
Green,Pink
Orange
Purple,Blue
```

I'm trying to write an if statement to occur when the string does NOT contain a comma.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strpos($string, ",") === false` -> no comma.

Comment: And do note that it has to be ===, not ==

Comment: Slight nitpick... The fields with single values *are* comma-separated just like the multi-value fields.  They just happen to be a list of 1.  Is your application logic really asking "which fields don't have a comma" or is it actually asking "which lists are a length of 1"?

Comment: Hi - i'm going to use
if (strpos($entry['3'], ",") === false && $entry['8'] < 9)
{
  $leadtype = 'livepricer';

}